# Send an email as pdf attachment in infopath 2010

Tags: infopath

I have a InfoPath form associated with document library. Form has submit and cancel button right now we have the data to be sent to document library when clicked on submit button. Now i am looking to send email as well and also to submit the data to library. I want the email to be sent with form as pdf. Is it possible in InfoPath designer and can someone suggest on this. This is on SharePoint 2010. Thanks in advance.